# MS SQL: Nested Selects - Mysterious "Invalid column name" error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

When I run the following query against a MSSQL 2000

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(Email),
    (SELECT TOP 1 ActivityID
        FROM Activity aa, ActivityType tt 
        WHERE aa.ActivityTypeId = tt.ActivityTypeId 
            AND aa.ConsumerID = c.ConsumerID
            AND tt.ActivityType = 'Something_OptIn') optin,
    (SELECT TOP 1 ActivityID
        FROM Activity aa, ActivityType tt 
        WHERE aa.ActivityTypeId = tt.ActivityTypeId 
            AND aa.ConsumerID = c.ConsumerID
            AND tt.ActivityType = 'Something_OptOut') optout
FROM
    Activity a,
    Consumer c,
    ActivityType t
WHERE
    c.CountryID = '23'
    AND t.ActivityType = 'Something_Create'
    AND a.ActivityTypeId = t.ActivityTypeId
    AND c.ConsumerID = a.ConsumerID
    AND optin > 1
```

I get the following error

```
Server: Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Invalid column name 'optin'.
```

Why does this happen? I can't see why it would be invalid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server does not allow you to refer to aliases by name at the same level.  To fix this, repeat the column definition:

```
WHERE
    c.CountryID = '23'
    AND t.ActivityType = 'Something_Create'
    AND a.ActivityTypeId = t.ActivityTypeId
    AND c.ConsumerID = a.ConsumerID
    AND (SELECT TOP 1 ActivityID
        FROM Activity aa, ActivityType tt 
        WHERE aa.ActivityTypeId = tt.ActivityTypeId 
            AND aa.ConsumerID = c.ConsumerID
            AND tt.ActivityType = 'Something_OptIn'
        ) > 1
```

Or use a subquery:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT(Email),
            (...) optin,
            (...) optout
        FROM
            Activity a,
            Consumer c,
            ActivityType t
        ) as SubqueryAlias
WHERE
    c.CountryID = '23'
    AND t.ActivityType = 'Something_Create'
    AND a.ActivityTypeId = t.ActivityTypeId
    AND c.ConsumerID = a.ConsumerID
    AND optin > 1
```

Comment: It does work with only one nested SELECT, but not with the optin and optout. See https://gist.github.com/71efc3aa5bff219e98d7.

Comment: @jwandborg: The query you link to contains `= NULL`, but nothing is ever equal to null.  Even `null = null` is not true.  You're probably looking for `is null`.

Answer (score 1):

The last line `AND optin > 1` is the offender.

The `WHERE` clause knows nothing about column aliases in the SELECT list.

You should probably subquery this SELECT without the offending condition, and apply that condition to the outer SELECT.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
  ...
  WHERE ... /* everything except 'optin > 1' */
) anyAlias
WHERE optin > 1
```